# Laravel 4 Route and redirect not working 2 level path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm currently trying to implement redirects using

```
Route::get('people/foo', function() {
    return Redirect::to('people', 301);
});
```

That won't work, will give a 404, but doing 'people/foo/bar' will redirect correctly.

```
Route::get('people/foo/bar', function() {
     return Redirect::to('people', 301);
});
```

What could be the cause of this, I've tried different variants.

Comment: Probably you have other routes influencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have another route that's intercepting requests to `people/{whatever}` like:

```
Route::get('people/{id}', 'PeopleController@show');
```

or

```
Route::resource('people', 'PeopleController');
```

If so, then you'll need to place this specific route before that one.